# setScaleX / setScaleY to a decimal value

Tags: android-studio, layout, scale, scaletransform

When setting the scale of a view programmatically, setScaleX() and setScaleY() do not accept decimal values like **"0.1"** and displays the error code **"setScaleX(float) in View cannot be applied to (double)"** when such a value is specified.

setScaleX() and setScaleY() only seems to accept integers like **1, -5 or 10**.

How do you set this scale value to a decimal amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: This solution was incredibly easy, but I thought I would post this question anyway in case someone else was having the same problem.**

Simply add an **" f "** to the end of the value within the brackets of setScaleX() / setScaleY().

It will look something like this:

```
button.setScaleY(0.1f);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: When asking try to provide some code of what your have tried and the stacktrace of the error

setScale() accept float 

so cast your double to float something like this

Answer (score 0):

Because you are putting a `double` as an entry for `setScaleX()` methode so you should `cast` it to `float`

try this :

```
yourView.setScaleX((float) yourDoubleVariable);
```